# how to call imagepickerdelegate method two times when picking images from dirrerent button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image

I'm relatively new to X Code 
and 
I m working on photo collage App , when i pick image from one picker then image picker is working properly but i want to pick different images from different imagepicker then image picker is not working properly

Anyone help me solve my problem. Here is my code

`

```
-(IBAction)imagepickMethod1:(id)sender
{
    imagepicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagepicker.delegate=self;
    imagepicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagepicker animated:YES];
     button1.tag=100;
}
-(IBAction)imagepickMethod2:(id)sender
{
    imagepicker1=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagepicker1.delegate=self;
    imagepicker1.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagepicker1 animated:YES];


}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imagepicker.view.hidden=YES;


        photoPreviewImageView.image=image;


}
-(void)imagePickerController1:(UIImagePickerController *)picker1 didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image1 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo1
{
    [picker1 dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imagepicker.view.hidden=YES;
             photoPreviewImageView1.image=image1;

}
```

`

Comment: Please make your question more clear so that we could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Take two imageView in your .h file
UIImageView *imgViewForFirstPicker;
UIImageView *imgViewForSecondPicker;

// Alloc these images in view did load 

imgViewForFirstPicker = [[UIImaeView allo] initWithFrame:(give your rect)];

// Similarly for second imageView and add to both in self.view

-(IBAction)imagepickMethod1:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagepicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagepicker.delegate=self;

    imagepicker.tag=100;
    imagepicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagepicker animated:YES];
}
-(IBAction)imagepickMethod2:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagepicker1=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagepicker1.delegate=self;
    imagepicker1.tag=101;
    imagepicker1.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagepicker1 animated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage: (UIImage*)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if(picker.tag == 100)
    imgViewForFirstPicker.image=image;
    else
    imgViewForSecondPicker.image=image;
}
```

try this one hope it will help you

Comment: but in my app imagepicker.tag is not working.. Can u tell me what i do for this problem

Answer (score 0):

`UIImagePickerController` creates a pretty heavy object, So I don't think it is advisable to create multiple instances of it. May be this is what is causing the problem if you are doing the same.. It would be nice if you could share your code as well so we can have more insights into your problem

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to just use on image picker. From the code you provided you are trying to create two different imagepicker delegate methods, but in reality only one of them will be called both times.

You should create on instance of imagePicker and change its tag depending on which image you needed changed and then in the `-didFinishPickingImage` check `if (picker.tag == SOME_TAG)` then set appropriately.